# touchesEnded not getting called when combined with UIButton?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, touches, uianimation, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I've implemented that when the my `UIButton` is highlighted and my `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` recognizes the gesture it will begin an animation. The problem is I want to end the animation when `touchesEnded` gets called after selecting the `UIButton` and making a gesture. But `touchesEnded` never gets called if I tap a `UIButton` in the process.

The rest of the time it works, but its useless to me if I can't use it during my animation. Here is what I did:

```
-(IBAction) swipeDown:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
     if(onebutton.highlighted)
     {
          //Animate
     }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
    for(UITouch *touch in touches)
    { 
        if(touch.phase == UITouchPhaseEnded)
        { 
            NSLog(@"touched");
        } 
    } 
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of touchesEnded, you could add another action for your button that is triggered when it is released.

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapEnded) forControlEvents:(UIControlEventTouchUpInside|UIControlEventTouchUpOutside)];
```